# Chrome console refers to wrong location

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a problem with console in chrome(also this problem is similar in other browsers). It refers javascript error to location where there is no errors, also lots of this errors refer to empty part of code. For example [image: all-errors][image: console-error1]
[image: console-error2]
[image: console-error3]
[image: console-error4]

Comment: I've personally noticed that chrome debugger does not play well with html files. It's not a problem though - you just should keep your js in a separate `.js` files and all will be fine.

Comment: can you link to your images? they're not big enough to see the text

Comment: have you tried FireBug ?

Comment: sometimes error is in the previous line. i.e if you miss a semicolon ; and after it you have } the error will be showing } is not expected.

Comment: @Derek: they are big - just open them in a separate window.